# PHP: Copying as attribute value into another attribute

Tags: php, html, session-variables

Here's a snippet from my XHTML code:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="selector01" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['x']; ?>" />
  <button>next</button>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<form>
```

More input elements will be added dynamically when the button is clicked (using javascript). The value of "name" will be incremented (ie. *selector02, selector03, etc.*).

I'd like to copy the value of each "name" attribute and put it into the $_SESSION variable.

Comment: Do this instead, it'll make things better, readability wise in the future. `<input type="text" name="selector01" value="<?= $_SESSION['x'] ?>" />`

Comment: @FinalForm Short tags are not enabled everywhere.

Comment: Do you want to store the `name` attrs in `$_SESSION` as they are dynamically added, or when the form is posted?

Comment: @inti I understand, and he'll quickly see whether it's enabled on his server or not. I'm presenting him something better, if it's enabled.

Comment: I've edited my question to include the Submit button. At that point I want to pass my $_SESSION variables. The "next" button just adds new fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the input fields where the name starts with 'selector' use:

```
foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
    if ( substr( $key, 0, 8 ) == 'selector' ) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

If you want *all* form fields, use:

```
$_SESSION = $_POST;
```

as Neal suggested. You may need a little more validation if you use the second method to ensure that you don't overwrite existing session keys.

Answer (score 0):

You'd iterate through whichever method global you're referring to, and then you'd simply add the result:

```
foreach($_POST as $item => $value)
{
    if(strpos($item, 'selector') === 0) $_SESSION[$item] = $value;
}
```

Comment: `strpos($item, 'selector')` will search the value for the string 'selector'. You will want to search the key, then return the value on a match.

Answer (score 0):

On submit to `test.php`

do this:

```
$_SESSION = $_POST; // if no validation is needed
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not actually submitting the form for each button press, just dynamically adding new fields. If this is the case, then you can't directly manipulate a PHP variable from Javascript. JS is client side, PHP is serverside.

Comment: Yes, the "next" button just adds new fields. There is also a "submit" button. I was too concise for my own good! I'll edit my question.

Comment: In that case, you can't adjust SESSION from JS. You'll have to either submit the form on each iteration (and then use PHP to render a new form with a new field) or build a server-side AJAX handler that can take JS requests and subsequently manipulate SESSION.